# How to split ith element of every list within a nested list?

Tags: python, oop, for-loop

I am trying to achieve something similar to what the below code produces. Although the code below works perfectly fine, It is very repetitive. Is there a way to shorten the below code. Thank you.

```
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]
e=[]


trial_list =  [['a','2','3','4','5'],
               ['1','b','3','4','5'],
               ['1','2','c','4','5'],
               ['1','2','3','d','5'],
               ['1','2','3','4','e'],]

for each_line in trial_list:
    a.append(each_line[0])
    b.append(each_line[1])
    c.append(each_line[2])
    d.append(each_line[3])
    e.append(each_line[4])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip`, then tuple unpacking to assign the columns back into your variables.

```
a, b, c, d, e = zip(*trial_list)
```